# ls into an extracted directory

Tags: powershell, directory, unzip

Using PowerShell, I am downloading and extracting a file that has a directory and another file in it (it's basically from `https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows`). I'd like to be able to get into the directory after extraction.

So, in PS, I am at `c:\AzCopyTest` while downloading the file. It is being extracted at the same location. Here's the code for it:

```
$URL = "https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path c:\AzCopyTest
$Destination = "c:\AzCopyTest\zzz.zip"
$WebClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile($URL, $Destination).

$ExtractLocation = "c:\AzCopyTest"
$ExtractShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$file = $ExtractShell.NameSpace($Destination).Items()
$ExtractShell.NameSpace($ExtractLocation).CopyHere($file)
```

How can I get into the folder after the extraction is done? FYI, I don't want to `ls` into it directly (or manually instead). I'd like to be able to list out the items in that directory and get the first directory. `azcopy_windows_amd64_10.3.4` is what the directory called BTW. Now, when MS realease a new version (say 10.3.5), the directory will be renamed, and I do not want to go back in and manually change it. You get where I am going with this..

I know `Get-ChildItem -Path ("$ExtractLocation") -Recurse` will list the items in the directory and the sub-directories. But it does not server my purpose unfortunately.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:
`Get-ChildItem -Path $ExtractLocation -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object).Name` and it worked.

FYI, at a later time, if MS decided to add another directory in the zipped file, you can simple do this:

`Get-ChildItem -Path $ExtractLocation -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object).Name[<position_of_the_directory_starting_from_0]`